# Sort by defined values, if found

Tags: javascript, sorting

Using native ES2015 only (i.e. no libraries)
I need to sort a list of objects by a defined set of values (think T-shirt size) AND prioritize the ones that match one of the defined values.

Sample data:

```
const shirt_stock= [
    {size: "M"},
    {size: "L"},
    {size: "M"},
    {size: "XM"},
    {size: "XL"} ]
```

Defined sort order:

```
const sort_order = ["S", "M", "L", "XL"]
```

Sort code (no comments needed on use of indexOf() in sort, it's pseudo code):

```
shirt_stock.sort((a, b) => {
  return sort_order.indexOf(b.size) - sort_order.indexOf(a.size)
})
```

Yields result:

```
> 0: "XM"
> 1: "M"
> 2: "M"
> 3: "L"
> 4: "XL"
```

The problem is that first result, "XM" - I want that to be at the end. In other words, I want to sort shirts that have a known size first, in the order defined in `sort_order`, then everything else after - bonus if the "unknown size shirts" are also sorted so they're grouped by size.

Desired result:

```
> 0: "M"
> 1: "M"
> 2: "L"
> 3: "XL"
> 4: "XM"
```

I'm stumped, what's a clean (e.g. not splitting `shirt_stock` into two arrays, sorting and combing back) and reasonably efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` return `-1` for elements that are not found, which are then put first. You will need to use a value that's higher than all the other indices for those elements. Here's a quick way to achieve that:

```
shirt_stock.sort((a, b) => {
  return (sort_order.indexOf(a.size)+1 || sort_order.length+1) - (sort_order.indexOf(b.size)+1 || sort_order.length+1)
})
```

Since you already plan on not using `indexOf` directly in the callback, you'll probably find a more elegant way to incorporate these default values as well :-)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Ah, when I answered OP had not yet included the desired output, and given his original attempt (with `…b… - …a…`) I assumed he was looking for a descending sort. Updated - thanks for the hint!

Comment: I ended up using your syntax and you were first to answer, so I chose your answer. Thank you.

Comment: What? Was I wrong? I checked the "answered xx mins ago" and your number was small (i.e. you answer more recently)

Comment: @scubasteve Actually I was "last to the game" (about 5m), although I might have been the first to provide a working approach (disregarding the sort direction swap). It's really not a good metric for accepting answers - just choose the one that you like best.

Comment: @scubasteve :  *'...disregarding the sort direction swap'* :)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I really don't understand why you deleted your answer.

Comment: @Bergi : Considering my answer was *the first to provide a working approach **respecting** the sort order* I still prefer not to have it among my answers as this thread is a living example of all the crappiest things about SO

Comment: Sorry this went sideways and that I apparently misread who answered first. Anyway, thanks for the effort guys. Take care.